# JQuery addClass/removeClass on scroll

Tags: jquery, css

I have a nav bar which is set to 'display: none;' on my CSS stylesheet. My Jquery file adds a class when I scroll down a set amount of pixels on the page. The class changes the display property to 'block' making the nav bar visible.

See HTML Below

```
      <section class="content">

    <div class="post-details">
      <span class="date">Published 28/02/2018 by: <p><a href="#"></a>David Williams</p> </span>
      <div class="about">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Dolorum reiciendis, unde nobis, fugiat temporibus
        excepturi tempore dolor provident dolorem rem nostrum,
        eligendi nisi id voluptates atque vitae eveniet explicabo
        reprehenderit! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Dolorum reiciendis, unde nobis, fugiat
        temporibus excepturi tempore dolor provident dolorem
        rem nostrum, eligendi nisi id voluptates atque vitae eveniet
        explicabo reprehenderit!
      </div>
      <a href="#">View/Read More</a>
    </div>
    <a href="" ><div class="post"></div></a>

    <div class="full-width search">
      <div class="search-form">
        <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Search This Blog" autofocus="autofocus">
        <div class="close"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="one missing">
      <div class="logo">
      <img src="img/final15Logo.png">
      </div>
      <div class="container teal borderYtoX">
        <li><a href="#" class="active">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ARCHIVE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SUBSCRIBE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        <li><a class="search-icon"><i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="post-details">
      <span class="date">Published 28/02/2018 by: <p><a href="#"></a>David Williams</p> </span>
      <div class="about">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  consectetur adipisicing elit.
        Dolorum reiciendis, unde nobis, fugiat temporibus
        excepturi tempore dolor provident dolorem rem nostrum,
        eligendi nisi id voluptates atque vitae eveniet explicabo
        reprehenderit! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,  consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Dolorum reiciendis, unde nobis, fugiat
        temporibus excepturi tempore dolor provident dolorem
        rem nostrum, eligendi nisi id voluptates atque vitae eveniet
        explicabo reprehenderit!
      </div>
      <a href="#">View/Read More</a>
    </div>
    <a href="" ><div class="post"></div></a>
```

see JQuery below.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
console.log(scroll)
if(scroll >= 1300) {
$('nav.one').addClass('show');
  } else {
$('nav.one').removeClass('show');
 }
})
```

See original class below.

```
.missing {
  display: none;
}
```

See added class below.

```
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

This all works fine when I scroll down for 1300px My nav bar appears, however I would like it to disappear again after 2100Px. Here is thye code I am using which is not workking.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
  console.log(scroll)
    if(scroll >= 1300 && scroll <= 2100) {
    $('nav.one').addClass('show');
  } else {
    $('nav.one').removeClass('show');
  }
})
```

Using this code, when I scroll beyond 2100px it jumps back up to 2000px. Can anyone help? Is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: can you create a working code to reproduce this behavior

Comment: I can't see any problem here. Kindly add a working example.

Comment: That's because when you hide the element, the vertical space it takes up disappears so your scroll position changes back to 2000px (I suppose the element is ~100px in height). You will have to position the element such that it is out of the document flow, to avoid it's shown/hidden status from affecting scroll height/position.

Comment: @Terry if the first is working, i am pretty sure the element is positioned fixed ... if not we won't see it as it will be out of the screen. By the way without code we can never know what's happenning so let's hope he will spoil us with his code :)

Comment: @TemaniAfif It doesn't have to be. You are only showing the element in the first example, which increases the scroll height but does not affect your scroll position. Removing/hiding an element when you've scrolled past it will cause scroll position to change.

Comment: @Terry i agree ;) but since it's a nav, i suspect it's the common fixed nav we make appear with scroll after an amount of pixel

Comment: @TemaniAfif Again, you can't possibly assume that. It's a good heuristic though (with many examples out in the wild), but then again, there simply isn't enough code to see what the actual layout is.

Comment: Hi @TemaniAfif thank you for responding. I'm sorry but I'm not sure what you are asking

Comment: we are asking for more code :) HTML/CSS,etc .. we need to able to reproduce this behavior. So it will be good if you can create a working snippet

Comment: I have posted some HTML, I hope this helps. I am new to this site, and to code so sorry if I'm getting on anybody's nerves.

Comment: @Terry I believe you are right only, I don't think I'm experienced enough to test it. However I adjusted my CSS by replacing the display property with the opacity property. This has the desired effect without creating any obvious problems.